# INSTEAD OF TRIGGER, Would it infinitely loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Would an Insert Statement on a table that has an "INSTEAD OF" trigger cause an infinite "instead, insert" loop of executions?

For example this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER setDescToUpper ON part_numbers
INSTEAD OF INSERT

AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO part_numbers (
        colA,
        colB,
        part_description
    ) SELECT
        colA,
        colB,
        UPPER(part_description)
    ) FROM
        INSERTED
END
GO
```

Would the insert statement inside the "instead of" trigger cause a loop?

I dont wanna disable recursive triggers.

Do I need to temporarily disable the trigger?

Source: [SQL Server - after insert trigger - update another column in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341584/sql-server-after-insert-trigger-update-another-column-in-the-same-table/5341675#5341675)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This INSERT will not re-invoke the trigger.

SQL Server will not call INSTEAD OF triggers recursively, for exactly the reason you bring up.

Comment: +1 Right, it's an INSTEAD OF trigger.  [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx): "If an INSTEAD OF trigger defined on a table executes a statement against the table that would ordinarily fire the INSTEAD OF trigger again, the trigger is not called recursively. Instead, the statement is processed as if the table had no INSTEAD OF trigger and starts the chain of constraint operations and AFTER trigger executions."

Comment: Could you explain what would happen then in this scenario with an INSERT statement? Would the INSERT within the trigger still execute?

Comment: If you want recursive behavior, simply create a recursive stored procedure and call it inside the trigger. Note SQL Server's limit of (I think) 32 levels of recursion.