# Update inserted record on a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert, sql-update

I'm having troubles while trying to update a record when it is being inserted into a database via external application.

I need the record being inserted from the users in the application takes a value  `MinimumStock` from a table `AERO_LOCATIONSTOCKMIN` on which are the parent location and the asset type

```
LOCATIONSTOCKMINID  ASSETTYPEID   LOCATIONID    MINIMUMSTOCK
   54000000001      54000000043   43200000357      12.00
   54000000002      54000000043   43200000883      6.00
```

This is the purpose: When a user tries to insert a record on `Asset` table (via external app), the trigger must to check if the user has selected a location for that `Asset`. If so, the trigger must retrieve the parent location for the selected location and check if there is stock minimum defined for this `AssetType` and for this parent location.

If all is fulfilled, the trigger must to set the field `UDFText01` to the minimum stock defined in the above table.

Here is what I've tried so far. The trigger is checking well the requirements, but it fails when trying to UPDATE and raising the following error:

`The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted`.

I tried to modify the UPDATE statement in many ways but all of them raises the same error message.

**EDIT**

*Following @Sean Lannge's suggestion I've edited my trigger in order to manage more than one inserts. The trigger is not longer showing the error message but the changes (insert) are not saved into database.*

```
ALTER TRIGGER [spectwosuite].[TRI_ASSET_STOCKMIN] ON [spectwosuite].[ASSET]
FOR INSERT AS 
BEGIN
  IF (UPPER(USER) != 'SPECTWOREPLENG')

    DECLARE @assettypeid numeric(15);
    DECLARE @assetid numeric(15);
    DECLARE @locationid numeric(15);
    DECLARE @parentlocationid numeric(15);
    DECLARE @stockmin numeric(9,2);
    DECLARE @mistock varchar(100);


    DECLARE crs_ROWS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ASSETID, ASSETTYPEID, LOCATIONID
    FROM inserted;

    OPEN crs_ROWS;
      FETCH NEXT FROM crs_ROWS INTO @assetid, @assettypeid, @locationid 
      WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
      BEGIN

            SELECT @parentlocationID = ParentLocationID FROM Location 
                    LEFT JOIN Asset ON Asset.LocationID = Location.LocationID
                    WHERE Asset.LocationID = @locationid;                   


            IF NOT EXISTS 
                (SELECT * FROM Location LEFT JOIN INSERTED AS i ON Location.LocationID = i.LocationID 
                    WHERE Location.LocationID = i.LocationID)
                BEGIN

                    RAISERROR ('Please fill the Location for the Asset.',16,1);
                    ROLLBACK;
                END
            ELSE            

                    IF EXISTS (SELECT MinimumStock FROM AERO_LOCATIONSTOCKMIN
                        WHERE AssetTypeID = @assettypeid AND LocationID = (SELECT ParentLocationID FROM Location WHERE LocationID = @locationID))

                        BEGIN

                            SELECT @stockmin = MinimumStock FROM AERO_LOCATIONSTOCKMIN
                                WHERE AssetTypeID = @assetTypeID AND LocationID = 
                                        (SELECT ParentLocationID FROM Location WHERE LocationID = @locationID);

                                SELECT @mistock= CONVERT(varchar(100),@stockmin);   
                                --RAISERROR (@mistock,16,1);            


                                UPDATE spectwosuite.ASSET
                                SET UDFText01 = @mistock 
                                FROM
                                     INSERTED I
                                INNER JOIN spectwosuite.ASSET T ON
                                     T.AssetID = I.AssetID

                            --UPDATE spectwosuite.ASSET SET UDFText01 = @mistock
                            --  FROM spectwosuite.ASSET AS A INNER JOIN inserted AS I
                            --  ON A.AssetID = I.AssetID;                   

                        END

                    ELSE
                            RAISERROR ('The parent Location for the Asset Type doesn't have minimum stock defined',16,1);
                            ROLLBACK;

       FETCH NEXT FROM crs_ROWS INTO @assetid, @assettypeid, @locationid; 
      END;
      CLOSE crs_ROWS;
      DEALLOCATE crs_ROWS;

END;
```

Comment: Is the field UDFText01 one of the columns of the table which the user has entered data into (using the external application?)

Comment: @S.Krishna Yes it is.

Comment: I think in that case you will need to use 'instead of' trigger. See this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341584/sql-server-after-insert-trigger-update-another-column-in-the-same-table

Comment: But I'd like to let the external application do its own `INSERT` statement and then add my own `UPDATE` statement to set value to `UDFText01`. Is that possible?

Comment: I dont think that would be a good idea. When you use 'instead of' trigger, the insert is still happening from your external application, just that you are adding more inputs based on the scenario you've mentioned.

Comment: I tried to change my trigger to a `INSTED OF INSERT`. Same error message :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77798/discussion-between-s-krishna-and-equisde).

Comment: You whole trigger logic has a MAJOR flaw. You are using scalar variables and assuming there will only ever be one row in your insert. This needs to be a set based approach instead.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the advice. I've modified the trigger to manage more than one insert but the INSERT made by the external application is not commited on database. Do you know why?

Comment: Well...I have to say I am rather amazed you were able to convert that trigger so quickly. But in regards to why it isn't in your database I would need to see the new trigger code.

Comment: Oh no!!! You may have changed your trigger to now deal with multiple row operations but you have created a timebomb. DO NOT use a cursor in a trigger like this. Not to mention that you now have even worse problems. If any row throws an error it will rollback the entire insert.

Comment: @SeanLange Then how should I manage this?

Comment: Well it looks like you have three possible outcomes for each insert. Missing location, minimum stock not defined, success. I would create a temp table to hold any rows that are not valid. I will try to cobble something together. It is a bit challenging because I don't have these tables and don't really know what you are doing but I think I can get it pretty close.

Comment: There are four tables involved on the process. [Asset], [AssetType] [Location] and [LOCATIONSTOCKMIN]. The user inserts records via app in [Asset] and in the app it's mandatory to select an AssetType for that Asset. as you said there are 3 outcomes which I need to control by trigger. **1.-** The user have not selected Location for the Asset. **2.-** The user has selected Location but its ParentLocation is not defined on [LOCATIONSTOCKMIN] for the selected AssetType. **3.-** The user has selected Location and its ParentLocation is defined on [LOCATIONSTOCKMIN] for the selected AssetType.

Comment: @SeanLange i know that it is some difficult to explain here in words but a pretty close piece of code will be very helpful and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the extended discussion here see if something like this isn't a bit closer to what you are trying to do.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [spectwosuite].[TRI_ASSET_STOCKMIN] ON [spectwosuite].[ASSET] FOR INSERT AS 
IF (UPPER(USER) != 'SPECTWOREPLENG')
BEGIN

    create table #MyInsertedCopy
    (
        --whatever columns go here that you want to display for error rows
        ErrorMessage varchar(50)
    )

    insert #MyInsertedCopy
    select i.* --use your real columns, not *
        , 'Please fill the Location for the Asset' as ErrorMessage
    from inserted i
    left join Location l on l.LocationID = i.LocationID 
    where l.LocationID IS NULL

    insert #MyInsertedCopy
    select i.* --use your real columns, not *
        , 'The parent location for that Asset doesn''t have minimum stock defined' as ErrorMessage
    from inserted i
    left join AERO_LOCATIONSTOCKMIN a on a.AssetTypeID = i.AssetID
    left join Location l on l.ParentLocationID = i.LocationID 
    where a.AssetTypeID is NULL

    update a
    set UDFText01 = MinimumStock 
    FROM INSERTED I
    INNER JOIN spectwosuite.ASSET T ON T.AssetID = I.AssetID
    INNER JOIN AERO_LOCATIONSTOCKMIN a on a.AssetTypeID = i.AssetID
    INNER JOIN Location l on l.ParentLocationID = i.LocationID 

    IF EXISTS(select * from #MyInsertedCopy) 
        --do something to report that there are rows that failed
        select * from #MyInsertedCopy
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much @SeanLannge. Since I'm currently out of office, I will try your solution as soon as possible and revert with my comments. Again, many thanks for your time and dedication!!

Comment: After some modifications regarding table fields correlations (Eg: `a.AssetTypeID = i.AssetID` > `a.AssetTypeID = i.AssetTypeID`) your solution is working fine. Many thanks again!